# Is it worth it to upgrade my ram?

Tags: ram, responsiveness

I currently have a 1.9ghz amd processor and 4gb of ram. I'm wondering if it would actually make ubuntu ui faster if I upgraded to 8gb or is it not worth the bother with my current processor?

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing with your computer. Try running `top` whenever your computer starts choking and see if the bottleneck is in CPU or in memory

Comment: Depends on if your system can handle more than 4GB at all. There's not much information in your question.

Comment: I've looked it up and it can handle up to 8

Comment: why did someone downvote this? I was asking a question as to if the extra ram would increase the smoothness of ubuntu specifically since ubuntu as an os doesn't usually seem to have the ui slow down much under program load, I was asking if it would be noticable in daily use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory is used for applications to store data while they are running. Programs use memory for data they will access often, instead of reading and writing to the hard drive which is much slower. If you don't have many applications running at the same time, you will probably not reach the point where you need to use 8GB of RAM, so the extra 4GB of RAM may not have much of a noticeable effect on how fast your system runs. You can open the System Monitor or run `top` from the terminal to see how much memory you are using. In particular, a running instance of a virtual machine will use as much memory as is allocated to it in the virtual machine application's settings.